# Duvida do uso de If, While ou for

Tags: python

Sou novo na programação de python.
Tenho um vetor com valores variando de 0 a 200 aleatoriamente e quero fazer uma rotina para eliminar (remover) os valores que estejam abaixo de 30 e acima de 160, e criar um novo vetor com esse valores.

Comment: E qual a dúvida exatamente?

Comment: Publique o código que você tentou e não conseguiu, para melhor ajuda-ló

Comment: Algo assim `if ($item > 30 && $item < 160)` dai voce pode jogar o dado dentro de outro array caso ele passe na validação

Answer (score 3):

Juarez, a melhor maneira de fazer esse tipo de filtragem é através da técnica de [compreensão de listas](http://blog.alura.com.br/simplicando-o-processamento-com-compreensao-de-lista-do-python/):

```py
vetor_filtrado = [valor for valor in vetor if 30 <= valor <= 160]
```

Isso assume que o vetor ao qual você está se referindo chama-se, de fato, `vetor`, se não ficou claro.

Com as suas especificações:

```py
excluidos = [valor for valor in vetor if valor < 30 or valor > 160
vetor = [valor for valor in vetor if 30 <= valor <= 160]
```

O código não apaga de fato os valores da lista, porque isso não seria esperto, mas sim cria uma outra com os valores corretos.
Espero ter ajudado :D!

Comment: Yan tenho duas variáveis m1 e m2 e um vetor (medidas)com valores, preciso ver se os valores do vetor são maiores que m1 ou menores que o m2 e exclui-los caso sejam. E lista para ver quais valores foram excluídos.

Comment: Juarez, entendi, mas minha explicação não ficou clara? :(. Vou editar a resposta pra ficar mais específica ao seu problema.